# Activity Stack not cleared

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my application when user logged out, user is send to login activity. But when user press back key, user is sent to the main activity.
How can i avoid this?

Here is my code executed when user press logout button.

```
button.Click += (sender, args) =>
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        SetDriverStatues("Logoff");
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_setdstat2", "set driver status failed");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    session.logoutUser();
                                    var mact = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
                                    mact.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                                    mact.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                                    StartActivity(mact);
                                };
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `finish()` to close the current activity.